# set_select() is marking every option as selected

Tags: codeigniter

The `set_select` function of CodeIgniter 3 is always selecting the last option of any `select` input when I click to edit some existing item.

I will just show the first two `select`s, which is below:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="id_marca">Marca do Carro</label>
    <select id="id_marca" name="id_marca" class="form-control" required>
        <option value="" selected disabled>Selecione</option>
        <?php foreach ($marcas as $m) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $m['id']; ?>" <?php echo set_select('id_marca', $m['id'], true); ?>>
                <?php echo $m['nome_marca']; ?>
            </option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="id_modelo">Modelo do Carro</label>
    <select id="id_modelo" name="id_modelo" class="form-control" required>
        <option value="" selected disabled>Selecione</option>
        <?php foreach ($modelos as $m) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $m['id']; ?>" <?php echo set_select('id_modelo', $m['id'], TRUE); ?>>
                <?php echo $m['nome_modelo']; ?>
            </option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Below is a screenshot of the problem. As it can be seen in the Inspector, every `option` is selected.

[image]

I made it work few days ago, and now magically does not work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code that you put true as third parameter in all of your option

set_select('first parameter will be name', 'second parameter will be the value', 'third parameter will be the "true/false" which make this value selected or not')

i think you need to look at [this](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

**UPDATE**

```
$options = array(
                  'small'  => 'Small Shirt',
                  'med'    => 'Medium Shirt',
                  'large'   => 'Large Shirt',
                  'xlarge' => 'Extra Large Shirt',
                );

$shirts_on_sale = array('small', 'large');

echo form_dropdown('shirts', $options, 'large');

// Would produce:

<select name="shirts">
<option value="small">Small Shirt</option>
<option value="med">Medium Shirt</option>
<option value="large" selected="selected">Large Shirt</option>
<option value="xlarge">Extra Large Shirt</option>
</select>
```

you could see [this](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

Sorry about that

**UPDATE 2**

```
<select name="myselect">
<option value="one" <?php echo set_select('myselect', 'one', TRUE); ?> >One</option>
<option value="two" <?php echo set_select('myselect', 'two'); ?> >Two</option>
<option value="three" <?php echo set_select('myselect', 'three'); ?> >Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I thought that CodeIgniter would verify it automatically. It is weird because I already did it just like this and I am sure when editing something the options were correctly selected.

Comment: So how do I check if the field is selected? CI could be smarter about it.

Comment: CI will do what ever you till it to do, so you need to specify which option you need to be selected

Comment: Yes, I understand. But the point is that if there is a method just to write `selected="selected"`, but still is necessary to write an `if` statement to actually check whether the `option` is selected, then it makes no sense at all to have a method like this, because I can simply write `selected="selected"` instead of this large method. But I believe something must've gone wrong here, it worked before without any condition.

Comment: you could pass the $value you want to be selected as third parameter for form_dropdown().

Comment: This is confusing. This example simply uses this `form_dropdown()`. How do I use it with `set_select()`??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98391/discussion-between-alaa-m-jaddou-and-mfgabriel92).

Comment: I solved with this `<?php echo set_select('id_marca', $m['id'], $modelo->id_marca === $m['id']); ?>`.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts anyway! :)